# Apex charts x axis zoom acting weird

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I have 2 questions about the x axis behaviour in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-davinci-6gwyx).

1. I am able to zoom OUT beyond the minimum - which shrinks the data volume, and makes the x axis show ticks that aren't really there (the data starts at 2004, but when zoomed out too much I see things before 2000 etc.). How do I stop this?
2. When zoomed IN, the x axis makes stand-in labels, but there is no data there and the labels are formatted to only show the year, so I get duplicate year labels which is weird. How do I stop this?

Thank you in advance.